# Deleting a SharePoint Team Site using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have a Power Automate workflow that is doing a lot of different things, and at the end, it tries to delete a Team Site (site collection) in my SharePoint Online tenant.  I am using an HTTP action to do this, and it looks like this:

```
Site Address: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyy
Method: POST
Uri: _api/web
Headers:
"accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
"content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
"X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
```

The error is

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 502,
    "source": "flow-apim-msmanaged-na-westus-01.azure-apim.net",
    "clientRequestId": "1ed0536f-78f3-45cc-a636-a10af5d670f0",
    "message": "BadGateway",
    "innerError": {
      "status": 502,
      "message": "Cannot delete top-level site: https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyy.\r\nclientRequestId: 1ed0536f-78f3-45cc-a636-a10af5d670f0\r\nserviceRequestId: 668965a0-c019-2000-72ee-7660a568e911",
      "source": "https://xxx.sharepoint.com/sites/yyy/_api/web",
      "errors": [
        "-2146232832",
        "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is this possible from Power Automate, and if so, what should I be doing differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is a modern site (Communication sites and Non-group associated Team Sites) you should be able to use the _api/SPSiteManager endpoint in a Send an HTTP request to SharePoint action.

[Delete a modern site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/site-creation-rest#delete-a-modern-site)

```
url: /_api/SPSiteManager/delete
method: POST
accept: application/json;odata.metadata=none
odata-version: 4.0
body:
{
  "siteId":"d11e59ca-1465-424c-be90-c847ba849af5"
}
```

When it is a group connected site I would use the [Delete Group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) method from the Graph API in a Send an HTTP request action of the Office 365 Groups connector.

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}
```

Comment: I can delete the Group using the second API call you mention here, but that doesn't delete the SharePoint site.  So should I use these two calls in parallel and delete the group, then the Site?  Or should my group deletion be deleting my site as well?  If so, that doesn't appear to be happening.

Comment: Yes, it should also delete the site. But the deletion will not happen instantly. It is probably a job running in the background. And I believe it is a soft delete (30 days retained, just in case). Both the group and the site will still be in the delete group and delete sites views of both admin centers.